# Drawing graphs on java

Tags: java, graph, drawing, nodes

I want to draw graphs (nodes and edges) in Java. However, since I don't know how to go about it, I would like to have some advice before starting.

How should I do this?

use Graphics2D package, right?

How about the labels for the nodes? should I use something like drawString and handle all the "centering" manually or create a JLabel for that? Can I put a JLabel on a Graphics2D environment?

I have searched but haven't found any simple implementation of this. If you know of one, please provide the link in your answer.

edit: The solution I am looking for should be able to remove nodes, drag nodes, edit labels, create nodes, all with mouse events.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"[Graph Panel](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/graphpanel) is a simple example of an object drawing program." More complex alternatives are cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10129994/230513).

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps this will help: [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/).

And you will probably need to read this: http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/JUNGVisualizationGuide.html

Answer (score 7):

[JGraphT](http://jgrapht.sourceforge.net/) and [JGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/jgraph.html) are another option.  JGraph is used for rendering graphs in the GUI and handling user interaction while JGraphT is the underlying graph model, data structures and algorithms.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do it yourself the [GraphLayout examples](http://java.sun.com/applets/jdk/1.4/index.html) will help.

[This is a good example](http://java.sun.com/applets/jdk/1.4/demo/applets/GraphLayout/example1.html) with only a few lines of code.

If you want to use a more sophisticated framwork check [JGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/jgraph.html)

Comment: The example link is removed. Do you have any other link(s)?

Comment: @David http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/example1-138026.html

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of choices. [The GVSR Project](http://gvsr.polytech.univ-nantes.fr/GVSR) maintains a list. You can limit your search to [Java libraries](http://gvsr.polytech.univ-nantes.fr/GVSR/task?action=compare&path=root,t101,t103) only.

Comment: URLs are dead! any updates?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest grappa. http://www.research.att.com/~john/Grappa/grappa.tgz