# Drawing line graphs in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Drawing graphs on java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981825/drawing-graphs-on-java)

I have created a calculator for BMI. I need to draw line graph to show results.

Comment: @doggbane: i think he need to draw graph in `GWT`. and question you have posted doesnt seem to contain anything related.

Comment: What do you need help with?  You haven't really asked a specific answerable question yet.

Comment: have you tried LineChart class or anything else? what you have tried yet? do you get error in trying something or have ant restriction on using anything? :http://gwt-google-apis.googlecode.com/svn-history/r1132/javadoc/visualization/1.0/com/google/gwt/visualization/client/visualizations/LineChart.html

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [GWT Chart Tools (aka Visualization API)](http://code.google.com/docreader/#p=gwt-google-apis&s=gwt-google-apis&t=VisualizationGettingStarted).

Comment: i have written a code for BMI to display the calculated result in a message box.but i want to draw graph similar to graph given in this.http://www.healthizen.com/health-tools/calculators-trackers/body-mass-index-bmi-calculator.aspx PLEASE help me.