# Problems dynamically drawing a tree

Tags: java, swing, graphics, tree, paintcomponent

I have already searched for answers. Some topics that pointed me in the right direction are:

[How to draw a tree representing a graph of connected nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126695/how-to-draw-a-tree-swing-awt-swt-jface)
http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/151175/drawing-tree-with-jframe

Anyway, here is the problem. I need to be able to draw a tree into a JFrame using no third party stuff; just methods available in swing. The code I have is below: the Tree class I didn't include, but it takes a text file and parses it into the tree structure. I'm running into two problems: First, I can't get the value for the node to show up in the oval. The value is stored as a string and should get passed through the Node. Second, the lines are not showing up, even though I overwrote paintComponent. Can someone help?

The NodeLabel:

```
public class NodeLabel extends JLabel{

public Node node;
public Point topConnection;
public Point bottomConnection;

public NodeLabel(Node _node){
    super(_node.value);
    node = _node;

    this.setText(node.value);
    this.add(new JLabel(node.value));
    topConnection = new Point(this.getWidth()/2, 0);
    bottomConnection = new Point(this.getWidth()/2, this.getHeight());
}


@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    g.drawOval(5,  5,  25, 15);
}
```

The DrawTree Class:

```
private ArrayList<NodeLabel> nodes;
private Tree tree;
private NodeLabel root;
private int currentX;
private int currentY;

public DrawStuff(Tree _tree){
    tree = _tree;
    currentX = 40;
    currentY = 0;
    this.setLayout(null);
    this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300, 300));

    root = new NodeLabel(tree.root);
    root.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    this.add(root);
    root.setBounds(currentX, currentY, currentX + 20, currentY + 25);
//      root.setLocation(currentX, currentY);



    currentX = currentX - 20;
    currentY = currentY + 30;

    for(Node node : tree.root.children){
        NodeLabel temp = new NodeLabel(node);
        this.add(temp);
        temp.setBounds(currentX, currentY, currentX +20, currentY + 25);
        this.add(drawEdge(this.getGraphics(), root, temp));

        temp.setLocation(currentX, currentY);
        currentX += 40;


        System.out.println("child added");
    }

}

private JPanel drawEdge(Graphics g, NodeLabel parent, NodeLabel child){     
    final Point p1 = parent.bottomConnection;
    final Point p2 = child.topConnection;

    JPanel line = new JPanel(){
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawLine(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y);
        }
    };

    return line;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    Tree tree = new Tree(args[0]);
    System.out.println(tree.toString());
    DrawStuff dTree = new DrawStuff(tree);
    dTree.setVisible(true);
}
```

The Tree Class: The tree takes a well-formed file (almost xml) and stores it in the data structure. Tags are formed like so: , with nested tags showing the hierarchy. IE:

public class Tree {

```
Node root;

/**
 * Tree constructor method
 * Takes the file and constructs a tree based on the contents
 * @param filename the name(or path) of the file to extract information from
 */
//Take the file and create all the nodes
public Tree(String filename) throws Exception{
    File file = new File(filename);
    Scanner s = new Scanner(file);

    Node current = new Node("x");
    if(s.hasNext()){
        s.next();
        String temp = s.next();
        String value = temp.substring(0, temp.length()-1);
        root = new Node(value);
        current = root;
    }
    while(s.hasNext()){
        String temp = s.next();
        if(temp.charAt(1) != '/'){ //then it is an open Tag.
            temp = s.next(); //this is our value + ">"
            String value = temp.substring(0, temp.length()-1);
            //create a new node with the value that's the child of our current node
            Node tempNode = current.addChild(value
                    );
            //current = the node we just created
            current = tempNode;     
        } else{
            if (current.parent!= null){
            current = current.parent;
            }
        }
    }
}

public String toString(){
    return root.toString();

}


public class Node{

    Node parent;
    ArrayList<Node> children;
    String value;

    public Node(String value){
        children = new ArrayList<Node>();
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Node(String value, Node parent){
        this.parent = parent;
        children = new ArrayList<Node>();
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Node addChild(String value){
        Node temp = new Node(value, this);
        this.children.add(temp);
        return temp;
    }

    public String toString(){
        String result = "";
        result += this.value + "\n"; 

        for(Node child:children){
            result += "    " + child.toString();
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of serious issues that I can see.  To start with, don't use multiple components to render distinct elements in this way.  Instead, create a single custom component which has the capacity to render the whole content.  This overcomes issues of coordinate context, which you don't seem to understand...

Start by removing the `extends JLabel` from the `NodeLabel` class, this class should simply be `drawable` in some way, so that you can pass the `Graphics` context to it and it will paint itself.

Create a `TreePanel` which extends from something like `JPanel`.  This will act as the primary container for your tree.  Provide a means by which you can set the tree reference.  Override the component's `paintComponent` method and render the nodes to it, drawing the lines between them as you see fit...

Take a closer look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) for more details

Comment: I wish I understood everything you just said. This is about the... 3rd time, I think... that I have every used swing. My limited GUI knowledge comes from actionscript, which is a little different. I thought everything had to be a component :/

Okay, so I can make the TreePanel the only component. How do I add something like the NodeLabel to the panel if it's not a component? Also, is drawable an interface that I have to implement for the label, or do I just need to override the paintComponent method to make it drawable?

Comment: You don't have to "add" anything to `TreePanel`, provide it with a reference to `Tree` and use the `paintComponent` method to render the nodes and lines as you see fit.  If you can provide your `Tree` implementation it might be easier to provide more details

Comment: You could also just use [`JTree`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html)

Comment: Okay, tell me if I have this right: If I make TreePanel a JPanel, I can override the paintComponent method, inside of which I can call methods like paintNode or drawLine, which I write in custom classes, as long as they take a Graphics object. I can even call these in a loop and dynamically create the nodes based on the Tree object I pass in.

If all of that is right, the only thing I don't get is: what is the original Graphics object that keeps getting passed around?

Comment: The `Graphics` context is provided to via the `paintComponent` method, this tells you that the component must be repainted...don't maintain a reference to it beyond the scope of the actual method call though...it's a one time deal ;)

Comment: Okay, so the Graphics is not something I have to worry about; it gets created, discarded, and garbage-collected without anything on my part. I think I can get this now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Oh, one last question: If I'm drawing the nodes in my Node classes, how do I add the text to them? Do I have to add a textLabel like I do in AS3, or can I call something like g.drawString?