# Draw Binary tree using java swing using mouse events methods

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I am able to draw ovals wherever I want to represent the nodes using mouseClicked method and then join them using mouseReleased method and a JButton which enables me to select two ovals between which I want to draw a line. 
After this I have to do non recursive preorder,postorder and inorder traversals by highlighting the nodes. I know how to perform them and print the output to the console if I have a created a Binary tree without the Swing functionality. The swing functionality is just creating an image and not storing any tree for me.
How do I perform the traversals using the image I have drawn of the tree?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10126695/230513) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15697697/230513).

Comment: @Andrew Thompson Sorry for forgetting to post the actual question. I have added the question now.