# Add GraphStream graph into my custom jPanel

Tags: java, swing, graph, jpanel, graphstream

I am working on GraphStream library. For now, When I run my program it opens new window for my graph and separate window for my graph. I tried to create a `JFrame` and add `JPanel` into `JFrame`, after all this I tried to add graph into my `JPanel` but it says that graph object is not a component.

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import org.graphstream.graph.*;
import org.graphstream.graph.implementations.*;

public class GraphExplore {
    static Connection conn2;
    static String result, result2;
    static JFrame frame;
    static JPanel panel;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    showData();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private static void showData() throws SQLException {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setBounds(30, 50, 1300, 600);
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        frame.setContentPane(panel);

        Graph graph = new SingleGraph("tutorial 1");
        graph.setAutoCreate(true);
        graph.setStrict(false);
        graph.display();

        // panel.add(graph);

        try {
            Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
            conn2 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:file:G:/hs_data/h2_db/test", "sa", "sa");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Statement stmt2 = conn2.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery("SELECT ANUMBER,BNUMBER,DATETIME FROM TEST");
        while (rs2.next()) {
            result = rs2.getString("ANUMBER");
            result2 = rs2.getString("BNUMBER");
            graph.addNode(result);
            graph.addNode(result2);
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < 200; i++)
                graph.addEdge("string" + i, result, result2);
            // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, i);
        }

        for (Node node : graph) {
            node.addAttribute("ui.label", node.getId());
        }

    }

}
```

This program opens separate windows for both `jframe` and graph. I want to show my graph into my `JFrame` or `JPanel`. Any idea about how to do this? I have seen this [link](http://graphstream-project.org/doc/Tutorials/Graph-Visualisation/1.0/), but it doesn't explains me well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in [*Graph Visualization: Advanced view: Integrating the viewer in your GUI*](http://graphstream-project.org/doc/Tutorials/Graph-Visualisation#advanced-view), "you will need to create the viewer by yourself." Also, call `setVisible()` *after* you have constructed the frame.

> It shows error on `frame.add(view)`.

It looks like the tutorial cited is a little dated. The [`Viewer`](https://data.graphstream-project.org/api/gs-core/current/org/graphstream/ui/view/Viewer.html) method `addDefaultView()` now returns a `ViewPanel`, which *can* be added to a `Container`. In the complete example below, a border is set on an enclosing `JPanel` having `GridLayout`, and that `panel` is added to the frame. Also note the need to give the `panel` a preferred size by overriding [`getPreferredSize()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513). Resize the window to see the effect.

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import org.graphstream.graph.*;
import org.graphstream.graph.implementations.*;
import org.graphstream.ui.swingViewer.*;
import org.graphstream.ui.view.*;

/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45055683/230513 */
public class GraphSwing {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new GraphSwing()::display);
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout()){
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(640, 480);
            }
        };
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue, 5));
        Graph graph = new SingleGraph("Tutorial", false, true);
        graph.addEdge("AB", "A", "B");
        Node a = graph.getNode("A");
        a.setAttribute("xy", 1, 1);
        Node b = graph.getNode("B");
        b.setAttribute("xy", -1, -1);
        Viewer viewer = new Viewer(graph, Viewer.ThreadingModel.GRAPH_IN_GUI_THREAD);
        ViewPanel viewPanel = viewer.addDefaultView(false);
        panel.add(viewPanel);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: It shows error on `frame.add(view);` " The method add(comp) in the type container is not applicable for the arguments (view) "

Comment: I've elaborated above.

Comment: This worked perfectly. The only issue is, All the nodes gathered at one point, and I have to drag every node by my self to have a clear vision.

Comment: If you don't set a node's `"xy"` attribute explicitly, try `viewer.enableAutoLayout()`.