# Drawing in java Edges/vertices

Tags: java, graph

hello people of Stack overflow,
i would like to know if there is a way to show a graph in Swing GUI preferably with no dependencies on external libraries , by graphs i mean edges and vertices

a sample graph would look like this

{origin Vertex ,destination Vertex , name of edge}

```
            {0, 1, "a"},
            {1, 0, "b"},
            {0, 2, "a,1,0"},
            {1, 2, "b,1,0"},
```

the output should look something like this (excuse my mspaint skills)
[image: outputgraph]

thanks for your time everyone.

Comment: Here is a [start](http://www1.cs.columbia.edu/~bert/courses/3137/hw3_files/GraphDraw.java)

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126695/how-to-draw-a-tree-representing-a-graph-of-connected-nodes) you might find what you want.      *@BelhadjAhmedWalid* provided you a good solution

Comment: both solutions look good to me i'll look into both of them if you find more suggestions please do add them, thank guys